# Confirm a unconfirmed user with Amazon Web Services after account creation (in app)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I had an issue in AWS where if you create a user account, leave the app, and go back in to confirm it using the code sent to email/SMS, then it will say that the username that you entered must be >1 character and it must follow some pattern. This is a bug in the sample code that amazon posted as well. I am posting here because there was no literature on the topic and I want to post my solution that worked because it was a very frustrating problem.

Here's the error:

> Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have
>   length greater than or equal to 1; Value at 'username' failed to
>   satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern:
>   [\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+";

When you initially create an account, you are taken to the confirm user storyboard where you have to enter a username and a code. The username however is already entered because you are technically logged in with an unconfirmed account. This is, however, the only time you will be able to log in with an unconfirmed account (unless you find some other work around). Therefore, if one was to segue back to the confirm user controller, they cannot simply type in the username because the code uses the logged in user's username, NOT the username entered. Here's how to fix that problem so you can simply enter the username and code and then confirm the account.

This is my first post in stack so here's my best answer:

in the method...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
```

change...

```
self.username.text = self.user!.username
```

to....

```
if self.user?.username == "" || self.user == nil {
    print("user is nil")
} else {
    self.username.text = self.user!.username
}
```

....and insert the following with YOUR poolID and in the @IBAction for your "Confirm" method and YOUR own SEGUE; insert it AFTER you check to see if the code value is empty and BEFORE the "self.user?.confirmSignUp" method...

```
if self.user?.username == "" || self.user == nil {
// change the poolid to yours
    let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(fenter code hereorKey: userPoolID)
// change the "username" title to whatever corresponds to the text field identifier you are using
    let user = pool.getUser((self.username?.text)!)

    user.confirmSignUp(self.code.text!, forceAliasCreation: true).continueWith {[weak self] (task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return nil }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        if let error = task.error as? NSError {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: error.userInfo["__type"] as? String, message: error.userInfo["message"] as? String, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            strongSelf.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:  nil)
        } else {
            // Change the segue identifier to yours
            strongSelf.performSegue(withIdentifier: "confirmedUserSegue", sender:sender)
        }
    })
return nil
}
}
```

Hope this helps!

To fix the resend code, do the same thing:

```
if self.user?.username == "" || self.user == nil {
            let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: userPoolID)
            let user = pool.getUser((self.username?.text)!)

            user.resendConfirmationCode().continueWith {[weak self] (task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
                guard let _ = self else { return nil }
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if let error = task.error as? NSError {
                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: error.userInfo["__type"] as? String,
                                                                message: error.userInfo["message"] as? String,
                                                                preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        alertController.addAction(okAction)

                        self?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:  nil)
                    } else if let result = task.result {
                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Code Resent",
                                                                message: "Code resent to \(result.codeDeliveryDetails?.destination!)",
                            preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        alertController.addAction(okAction)
                        self?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                })
                return nil
            }

        } else
```

... rest of code from amazon example in else statement...